# Convert string into numpy.ndarray python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I am getting a frame from opencv with type numpy.ndarray,now I want to convert this frame into string and then again convert it back to numpy.ndarray with the same datatype.
I have str(frame), now the problem is when converting str(frame) to numpy it throws error.

```
ret, frame = cap.read() # getting a frame
images = np.fromstring(str(frame),dtype=float,sep="")
```

but I am getting error **ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size**

Comment: Please provide the input data (`frame`) to clarify the problem.

Comment: type of frame is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and dtype is uint8 which I am getting from opencv and I want to convert this into string and back to again this type and dtype

Comment: This is only somewhat helpful. You need to provide a working example of `frame`

Comment: `str(array)` is meant to give humans a summary, not as a round trip like this.  Reread `fromstring` docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```py
>>> data
array([[ 79, 203, 231, 106,  17],
       [ 38, 114,  21, 251, 187],
       [222, 145,  59, 158, 211],
       [133, 150, 172,   5,  84],
       [166, 181, 171, 152, 197]])
```

**Convert to string**

```py
>>> data_str = ' '.join(map(str, data.ravel().tolist()))
>>> np.fromstring(data_str, sep=' ')
array([ 79., 203., 231., 106.,  17.,  38., 114.,  21., 251., 187., 222.,
       145.,  59., 158., 211., 133., 150., 172.,   5.,  84., 166., 181.,
       171., 152., 197.])
```

**Convert back to numpy array**

```py
>>> data_shape = data.shape
>>> np.fromstring(data_str, sep=' ').reshape(data_shape)
array([[ 79., 203., 231., 106.,  17.],
       [ 38., 114.,  21., 251., 187.],
       [222., 145.,  59., 158., 211.],
       [133., 150., 172.,   5.,  84.],
       [166., 181., 171., 152., 197.]])
```